# I have a script that runs an executable with a long path name. I want to stub out this executable so I can test the script

Tags: bash, sh, alias

As the title says, I have a script that launches an executable from a really long path name.  I cant actually make any changes to the script as its not mine, but I need to be able to test it.  I basically want to do something like this:

`alias /some/really/long/path/name/for/this/executable/run.sh='/usr/bin/echo'`

However, this wont work with the `/` in the alias name.

How can I run the script normally, but "stub" or "mock" that one line? The problem line is in a function, so I am able to `source` the script without any problems.  Im just not sure what to do once I have it sourced.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could run the script through sed first to replace the run.sh with whatever you want, then just run the sed output as test instead of the original. Should be 100% identical otherwise.

Comment: This is exactly what I needed.  Good call.

Answer (score 0):

You [cannot export aliases to scripts](https://superuser.com/a/447529/652023). If you have root rights, you could create a bind instead:

```
$ mkdir replacement
$ ln -s /usr/bin/echo replacement/run.sh
$ sudo mount --bind replacement /some/really/long/path/name/for/this/executable/
```

The bind will replace a directory with another one, similar to a symbolic link, but the original directory will remain unchanged after unmounting the substitute using

```
$ sudo umount /some/really/long/path/name/for/this/executable/
```

Either way, why don't you copy both scripts to your home directory and modify them locally?